# Why do I get a Heap Corruption when resizing a vector from inside a dll?

Tags: c++, dll, heap-corruption, xll

I am writing a XLL (using XLW library) that calls a DLL function. This DLL function will get a vector reference, modify the vector and return it by argument.

I have a VS10 solution with several c++ projects, some DLLs and a XLL that will call DLL functions from excel. I compiled everything using VS10 compiler, with `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0` and `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` and used same runtime library (/MDd) for all projects.

I also had to rebuild the XLW library to comply with `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0` that I have to use in my projects.

When calling the xll_function I was getting Heap Corruption errors and couldn't figure out why. 
After I tried resizing my vector before calling the dll function the error was gonne. That is, I can call the function and get the right vector returned by argument and no heap corruptions.

Could someone shed some light on this? 
As I am new to using DLLs I'm not sure if this should happen or if I am doing something wrong.

As you can see in the code below, the dll function will try to resize `forwards` and that is the point that I think is generating the heap errors.
I'm trying to understand why this happens and how this resizing and allocation works for dlls. Maybe I can't resize a vector allocated in another heap.

** Code below - the first function is a static method in a class from a dll project and the second function is exported to the XLL.

```cpp
void dll_function(double quote, const std::vector<double>& drift, const std::vector<double>& divs, std::vector<double>& forwards)
{
    size_t size = drift.size();
    forwards.resize(size);

    for( size_t t = 0; t < size; t++)
    {
        forwards[t] = (quote - divs[t]) * drift[t];
    }
}


MyArray xll_function(double quote, const MyArray& drift, const MyArray& divs)
{
    // Resizing the vector before passing to function
    std::vector<double> forwards(drift.size());

    dll_function(quote, drift, divs, forwards);

    return forwards;
}
```

Comment: ***Could someone shed some light on this?*** are you mixing compilers between the dll and the application? Only VS versions of 2015 or higher are compatible with each other. Binary compatibility does not exist between older versions or any other compiler.

Comment: I edited my question, thanks for the answers. I am really trying to understand if this is some bug or if this is the expected behavior from a dll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pass references to std::vector or other C++ collections across DLL boundaries, you need to do following.

1. Use same C++ compiler for both modules, and same version of the compiler.
2. In project settings, set up same value to the setting General / Platform Toolset.
3. In project settings, set up C/C++ / Code Generation / Runtime Library value to “Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)”, or Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd) for debug config. If one of the projects have a dependency which requires static CRT setting, sorry you’re out of luck, it won’t work.
4. Use same configuration in both sides: if you’ve built debug version of the DLL, don’t link with release version of the consuming EXE. Also don’t change preprocessor defines like _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL or _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS, or if you did, change them to the same value for both projects.

The reason for these complications, C++ doesn’t have standardized ABI. The memory layout of std::vector and other classes changes based on many things. Operators `new` and `delete` are also in C++ standard library, i.e. you can’t allocate memory with C++ in one module, free in different one.

If you can’t satisfy these conditions, there’re several workarounds, here’s a nice summary: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL

Comment: Tip: use a shared property sheet (.vsprops) file for this.

Comment: I usually don't upvote when we have to guess about the question because the OP is silent however this is a good answer so it gets my +1.

Comment: I'd argue that 1. is not exactly true. It's enough to use the compiler with the same ABI (which is usually the case) and ABI compatible stdlib (which was harder on Windows, but should be generally fine since VS 2015+). Although the latter often implies the former and vice-versa in the MSVC world.

Comment: ^ Agreed, you may want to mention something about the binary compatibility of VS2015 to VS2019.

Comment: @drescherjm I haven’t tried that. I don’t even have VS2019 installed on my PC, I usually wait for ~half a year before switching to another major versions. If you did, and you’re sure STL is indeed binary compatible across them, feel free to edit my answer.